# type: error message: [ ] operator not supported for string

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm getting information from database, saving it in array and echoing it in a form with loop structure and I'm having problems when I try to save the modified information to database.

I'm getting this error:

message: [] operator not supported for string

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_memory_questions');
        $this->db->order_by('rand()');
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $GetWordsFromdb = $this->db->where('memQuesType', 'Words');
        $GetWord = $GetWordsFromdb->get(); print_r($GetWord->result());exit;
        $GetWords = array();
        $MemQuesId = "";
        $GetsetId = "";
        $memQuesImgUrl = "";

        foreach ($GetWord->result() as $row) {
            $GetWords[] = $row->memQuesType;
            $MemQuesId = $row->memQuesId;
            $GetsetId = $row->setId;
            $GetsetIdarray[] = $row->setId;
            $GetmemQuesImgUrl[] = $row->memQuesImgUrl;

            $worddata[] = array(
                'GetWords' => $row->memQuesType,
                'MemQuesId' => $row->memQuesId,
                'GetsetId' => $row->setId,
                'GetmemuesImgUrl' => $row->memQuesImgUrl);
        }
```

I expect errorless word shuffle from database and show me the next page

could somebody give me hint what i'm going wrong?

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: [] operator not supported for strings

Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/moebiusutraLive/application/models/Memorytest_model.php

Line Number: 27

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `$worddata` as an array before you start referring to its elements by using the brackets. You are also failing to define `$GetsetIdarray` and `$GetmemQuesImgUrl` as arrays before trying to append elements to those vars.

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_memory_questions');
        $this->db->order_by('rand()');
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $GetWordsFromdb = $this->db->where('memQuesType', 'Words');
        $GetWord = $GetWordsFromdb->get(); print_r($GetWord->result());exit;
        $GetWords = array();
        $MemQuesId = "";
        $GetsetId = "";
        $memQuesImgUrl = "";

        $worddata = array(); // define these as arrays before you start
        $GetsetIdarray = array(); // trying to append elements
        $GetmemQuesImgUrl = array();

        foreach ($GetWord->result() as $row) {
            $GetWords[] = $row->memQuesType;
            $MemQuesId = $row->memQuesId;
            $GetsetId = $row->setId;
            $GetsetIdarray[] = $row->setId;
            $GetmemQuesImgUrl[] = $row->memQuesImgUrl;

            $worddata[] = array(
                'GetWords' => $row->memQuesType,
                'MemQuesId' => $row->memQuesId,
                'GetsetId' => $row->setId,
                'GetmemuesImgUrl' => $row->memQuesImgUrl);
        }
```